# How to Deploy EXE build to Amazon Web Service?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, deployment, exe

I created the application from the Unreal Engine. Unreal Engine, provides us the option to build the exe directly from the software. To run the application locally on any windows PC system it's working fine. But now, I want it to deploy the exe build to the AWS? What's steps/services required to get the application running online, I would like to know?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a Windows EXE app, build a web application using .NET libs and deploy that web app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. For more info, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html.

Comment: I am currently using Unreal Engine, which provides the feature to generate the EXE file from the software. I am not sure how to convert exe app to web application.

Comment: Come on @smac2020 he was asking a legit question. While unreal engine compiles his code and gives an executable, it can be run directly in the command line. Example; say the executable file from compilation is game.exe, running this directly in the command line will start the program as a service or a console application. How can this be done online and game clients will still be able to connect to the game server like in the local machine.